# Azure worker role stops after fault bucket event daily

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

Worker role instance stops daily and i get following error in WADWindowsEventLogsTable.

Instance status is unhealthy after this event is logged.

Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: PDUWICA
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: 8
P2: 1.6
P3: 6.3.0.0
P4: 1033
P5: 61
P6:
P7:
P8:
P9:
P10:

Attached files:

These files may be available here:

Analysis symbol:
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: a32d8f81-b668-11e5-80c8-000d3a316974
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket:

Comment: Please see this thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/eeff45d6-3caa-4925-a11e-b0ee76134e53/what-is-pduwica?forum=winserver8gen. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri : As mentioned on the thread from the link that there might be some scheduled task that cause issue, but in my case, i don't find any such scheduled task. Though the event is logged at same time daily.

Comment: Can you please add some details about the worker role?  Is it queue based, scheduled based, or just always running?  Have you put in the necessary sleeps?  Does the worker role restart correctly, or just remain in a downed state?

Comment: @CtrlDot : Only WebApi is deployed on the worker role. and its always running. When i restart the worker role it works as expected till the next day. and again went to unhealthy state and api stops working. I don't know about how to put necessary sleeps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable Intellitrace, re-deploy your instance (suggest to use local emulator if possible for a staging instance), get a more specific information about any unhealthy experience as posted and report the same? Review this link for a step by step guide on how to enable and use Intellitrace (http://justazure.com/microsoft-azure-cloud-services-part-5-debug-monitor-scale/)

**Edit:**

Once logged in to the instance with Remote assistance.

Try to access the Schedule Tasks, following is the screenshot on my PC and that might get you some specific information.

[image: Search for Schedule Tasks and run the scheduler]

[image: The scheduler screen looks like the following, try to dig in and look for anything suspicious]

Once the scheduler runs, try to dig in and look for anything suspicious

Comment: I guess, this is not the issue from the application, this is issue from the Azure WorkerRole, as it might run specific service/task at specific time daily and that causes the instance in unhealthy state. Intellitrace might not help for this issue.

Comment: @ChiragMakvana I understand your point, but did you really try other options suggested? For example, the log you posted seems incomplete to diagnose, making a simple Bing/Google search does not come up with anything helpful. So enable Remote Access to your instance and try to obtain more spefic information if possible.